# Pack independent linux binaries

Tags: c++, libraries, packaging

For the moment I use Gitlab with docker to create packages for different distributions. This works great but you have to create a docker images for every possible distribution you ship you bianries and create the package meta information for that. I was wondering if there is some tool which can create real independent packages like appimage but without running in a container. As I see it there must be a tool which copies all libraries (even ligc and libc++) to a designated folder and the binary has to use them at runtime.

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for something like [exodus](https://github.com/intoli/exodus), [flatpak](https://flatpak.org/), or [snaps](https://snapcraft.io/). Alternatively, just link everything into a static binary.

Comment: *"for every possible distribution"* - that's what you have to deal with when you want to support multiple distributions. And situation with linux fragmentation is getting even worse, for example even when targeting only 64-bit x86 ubuntu 18.04 it may be necessary to provide 4 different packages for each of the "LTS" distro variants.